# Configure phpmyadmin on Windows with Apache24

Tags: windows, apache, phpmyadmin

I am trying to configure phpmyadmin on my localhost Apache24 server. I change the root file of the server with one costum, everything works fine, and when I am trying to add phpmyadmin I get this

[phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2LXK.png)

I change the name of config.sample.inc.php into config.inc.php and a $cfg['blowfish_secret'] and doesn't help

[config.inc.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElU4P.png)

Thank you!

Comment: What stack are you using? (WAMP or LAMP for example)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention : WAMP

Comment: Then it's most likely the PHP is installed correctly, so check my answer about the DirectoryIndex below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have installed your PHP correctly, by clicking on the `index.php` link on the list of your printscreen.

If you see a login page it means your PHP is ok, but you haven't informed your Apache to use `index.php`.

Run down your Apache configuration to the directory index and add `index.php` to the DirectoryIndex line like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new with apache where is DirectoryIndex, could you detail a little bit the steps. Thank you!

Comment: And I don't see a login page in index.php

Comment: i created a file in my root directory .htaccess and added the line DirectoryIndex index.php and also into httpd.conf i added DirectoryIndex index.php instead of DirectoryIndex index.html and still not working

Comment: What file did you create?

Answer (score 0):

first sorry form my bad inglis but i am spanish.

To install phpmyadmin follow next steps, are so easy.

First remove and purgue all old phpmyadmin files with ...

```
sudo apt remove --purgue phpmyadmin
```

Next step is install it again, use this commnand ...

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
```

Enable *mbstring* mod to php

```
sudo phpenmod mbstring
```

Next step is change dir mod

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

File content:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Finaly restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you can't solve your problem with this steps reply me on this post.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am on windows.